# Problems installing xml2 in R

Tags: r, libxml2, xml2

When I try to install xml2 on an RStudio server I get the following error:

```
xml2_url.cpp: In function ‘Rcpp::List url_parse(Rcpp::CharacterVector)’:
xml2_url.cpp:85: error: ‘struct _xmlURI’ has no member named ‘query_raw’
xml2_url.cpp:85: error: ‘struct _xmlURI’ has no member named ‘query_raw’
make: *** [xml2_url.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘xml2’
```

My session info is

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale: 
[1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8   LC_NUMERIC=C  LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8   LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8   
[6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] devtools_1.8.0  digest_0.6.8    git2r_0.10.1    grid_3.1.1      httr_0.6.1      memoise_0.2.1   RCurl_1.95-4.3  rversions_1.0.0 stringr_0.6.2  
[10] tools_3.1.1     XML_3.98-1.1
```

The xml2 R-package perfectly installs on my macbook air...

Comment: You should upgrade your version of R, if you have administrator rights. Also, what is your OS?

Comment: I do not have administrator rights and work on redhat 5.5

Comment: I had the same problem using R 3.0.2 (ie the default version in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) but the problem was solved by adding the cran server in my source files and updating R to version 3.2. This needs admin rights. See the [cran web page](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/) for details

Comment: I have R 3.2.0 in RHEL 5 but I still get the same error.

Comment: @GowthamNatarajan: have you find a solution ? I'm stuck with the same issue.

Comment: No, but it seems it is caused by an old version of xml2. The field query_raw is not present in older versions.